# Merge or Map DataFrames with unique column names or on a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I need to copy 'CITY' names from `df2` to `df1`

```
df2 = 

S_ID CITY

XY   AA
XY   AA
XY   AA
XZ   AA
    
ZX   BB
ZX   BB
ZX   BB
ZY   BB
    
AS   CC
AS   CC
AS   CC
AD   CC

df1 =
 
S_ID P_ID
XY   1,2,3
XZ   5
ZX   4,6,7
ZY   9
AS   3,4,9
AD   1
```

expected output is

```
df1 = 

S_ID P_ID   CITY
XY   1,2,3  AA
XZ   5      AA
ZX   4,6,7  BB
ZY   9      BB
AS   3,4,9  CC
AD   1      CC
```

I tried to merge with this code

```
df = df1.merge(df2[['S_ID', 'CITY']], on='S_ID', how='left')
print(df)

S_ID P_ID   CITY
XY   1,2,3  AA
XY   1,2,3  AA
XY   1,2,3  AA
XZ   5      AA
ZX   4,6,7  BB
ZX   4,6,7  BB
ZX   4,6,7  BB
ZY   9      BB
AS   3,4,9  CC
AS   3,4,9  CC
AS   3,4,9  CC
AD   1      CC
```

And my resultant DataFrame `df` is not how I was expecting.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your output dataframe is correct, it only has duplicate rows. Try running `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['S_ID'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.drop_duplicates()` you got it almost right.